# Do all messages from logged users go through the same fix session?

Tags: fix-protocol

I'm trying to build a project structure for an application we are working on at my job. Really new to the fix-protocol world.

What I don't understand is, do/should all messages go trough the same client-server session or is a new session created for each user that logs in the app? I'm thinking the first option is more optimized than the other becauase it would generate less load to the fix engine, but I want to know what the best practice is.

Comment: Do you use an existing FIX protocol infrastructure for the project? Because that will likely dictate the way how sessions should be used, which messages should be sent etc. Otherwise I think we know too little about the project to make recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Project hasn't started yet, but we are thinking in advance to save some time for later. By Fix protocol infraestructure do u mean the engine we are gonna use? If that's the case, we are most likely going for a custom QuickFixJ build. Everything else will be made from scratch.

Comment: I didn't mean the engine but rather the used messages, protocol version etc. But when you start from scratch it sounds like you are going to define all that. Is there a specific reason why you need to use a custom QFJ build?

Comment: I get it now, our fix version will be FIXT1.1 and the messages we are gonna implement are those referent to: Pre-Market Data information, instrument reference data, statistic data and order handling. One of the key elements we want to focus on for the project is speed, that's why we might have to customize quickfixj to reduce latency. The other option is buying an engine like onixS, but that's up to my bosses. For now I'm assuming we will keep using quickfixJ.

Comment: I think there is room for improvement regarding latency in QFJ. However, maybe you should try it out first and see if it performs good enough for your use case. It would be great if you could create pull requests in the QFJ project if you make improvements. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a *session* as being a socket connection between a FIX client and FIX server. When a FIX client opens such a socket connection, the first FIX message it sends is `Logon`, and fields in this message identify the FIX client to the FIX server. The FIX server can accept the connection by responding with a `Logon` message, or refuse the connection by closing the socket.

Based on the limited details provided in your question, I am going to guess that your "app" is a FIX client that does not create FIX messages on behalf of itself, but rather it acts as a delegation server. For example, there might be multiple users, each of which has their own GUI that sends messages (in a non-FIX format) to the delegation server, and the delegation server then translates these incoming messages into FIX format and acts as a FIX client to forward these messages on to the FIX server. In such a case, several options come to mind.

The first option is for the delegation server to open a separate socket connection to the FIX server for each user, and to use  the user-specific socket connection to send a `Logon` message with that user's credentials. Messages to the delegation server from *user 1* are delegated to the FIX server via *socket 1*, messages from *user 2* are delegated via *socket 2*, and so on.

The second option is for the delegation server to open a single socket connection to the FIX server, send `Logon` once, and then, in every message sent on behalf of a user, use header fields such as `OnBehalfOfCompID`, `OnBehalfOfSubID` or `SenderSubID` to identify the user (disclaimer: I have rarely had occasion to use such header fields, and my understanding of their intended purpose might be incorrect, so perhaps this suggestion is semantically flawed; if so, I hope another user here will correct me in a comment). Or perhaps the `Account` field in the message body might be used for this purpose.

The first two options are based on the assumption that the FIX server needs to know the identify of the individual users who are (indirectly) sending messages to it. A third option is relevant if all the users are trading on behalf of a single legal entity. In this case, there may not be a need to disclose the identity of the individual users to the FIX server, so the delegation server could have a single socket connection to the FIX server and sends a single `Logon` message to identify the legal entity, and never passes on details of individual users to the FIX server.

Comment: The header fields you mentioned are mainly used for routing between FIX sessions. I don't know what exactly will be implemented but one could also consider using `BE/UserRequest` messages for User logons/logoffs.